# How to pass parameter of captcha code in "csv data set config" @ jmeter

Tags: web, jmeter, captcha

The site  which I want to login has Email, Password and captcha image fields.
My question is: How can I add values from captcha image in "CSV data set config" ?

Please provide any views/suggestion for it..

Answer (score 0):

Consider either turning off captcha checking (but keep it showing because generation can be cpu-consuming) or adding output of correct code somewhere on ligin page, so you could extract it with regexp extractor.
If there would be simple plugin to recognize your captcha's, then captcha wouldn't make any sense as spammer could use it too.